# Is it a right situation to use the phrase?

Tags: expressions

"We apologize for any inconvenience you experienced"
Can I use the phrase when I am eager to apologize for an inaccuracy in documents?

Comment: "We apologize for any inconvenience you may have experienced."

Answer (score 1):

Just using "We apologize for the inconvenience" on its own is far more standard and used [pretty much everywhere.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+apologize+for+the+inconvenience%2Cwe+apologize+for+any+inconvenience&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwe%20apologize%20for%20the%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWe%20apologize%20for%20the%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwe%20apologize%20for%20the%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwe%20apologize%20for%20any%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWe%20apologize%20for%20any%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwe%20apologize%20for%20any%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cwe%20apologize%20for%20the%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWe%20apologize%20for%20the%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwe%20apologize%20for%20the%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwe%20apologize%20for%20any%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWe%20apologize%20for%20any%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwe%20apologize%20for%20any%20inconvenience%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!